# Why does my Hoya seeds?

Tags: houseplants

[image]I want to get my seeds from flowers Hoya but do not know how.

Answer (score 2):

You have to wait for seed pods to form  - these won't form at all if there are no pollinating insects (if the plant is indoors  year round, for instance). If the pods do  form, they take some time to ripen, and you have to wait for ripening to take place before collecting the seed. Further information on that here http://www.international-hoya.org/propogation.asp